# Check if all objects key values are falsy

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object

```
const currentData: CreateProjectData = {
  title: '',
  description: '',
  projectType: '',
  projectStart: undefined,
  projectTime: 0,
};
```

Is there a way to check if all the values in the object are falsy (e.g 0, undefined, '', ect.) without transforming the object into an array and then looping through it?

Comment: Any solution will necessarily involve a loop of some sort. You can get by without constructing an array, but that'd make the code more ugly, not less, why don't you want to use an array?

Comment: No, there is nothing that checks the objects values without some transformation.

Comment: No, you need to transform into array. `const allFalsy = Object.values(currentData).every(value => !value);`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I literally said "no, you need to transform into array".

Comment: You can make use of `for..of` loop if you really don't want to transform into an array but if I were you I would make some sort of benchmarking to see if there's really a need to avoid creating an array in this case. It'll make the code easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for...in loop to iterate the object and check for truthy values

```js
const currentData = {
  title: '',
  description: '',
  projectType: '',
  projectStart: undefined,
  projectTime: 0,
};

var checkFalsyObject = (data) => {
  for (var prop in data) {
    if (data[prop]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(checkFalsyObject(currentData));
```

But easier approach would be use `Object.values` to get all values and then `Array.prototype.every` to check if for all the elements the passed callback suffices.

```js
const currentData = {
  title: '',
  description: '',
  projectType: '',
  projectStart: undefined,
  projectTime: 0,
};

const areAllFalsy = Object.values(currentData).every(el=>!el);

console.log(areAllFalsy)
```

Comment: First, he's not transforming the object, he's building a new separate array from the object's values. Then, `I don't want an array` is an arbitrary constraint from OP. If you need an array to solve your problem in one line, then go for it. Why this random constraint? Third, this answer also includes a `for` loop solution in case OP is really deadly allergic to arrays. (Upvoted)

Comment: the part `every(el=>!el)` is just too elegant. Now, would anybody literally "transform" an object? I think he meant so that no extra array is created... but, I suppose O(n) space is a concern if `n` is big. For a non-array object, usually `n` is too small to be a concern

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an extra array to be created ever for this purpose:

```js
function isDubiousData(data) {
  for (let p in data)
    if (data[p]) return false;
  return true;
}

const currentData = {
  title: '',
  description: '',
  projectType: '',
  projectStart: undefined,
  projectTime: 0,
  budget: null,
  onTime: false,
  bankAccountBalance: 0n,
  teamCoherency: NaN,
  qualityIndex: -0
};

console.log(isDubiousData(currentData));

currentData.title = "0";
console.log(isDubiousData(currentData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to check all object values, unless you want to hard-code each possible property, any solution *will* involve a loop of some sort. If you want to do it without constructing any arrays, the only way to do it is with `for..in`:

```js
let allFalsey = true;

const currentData = {
  title: '',
  description: '',
  projectType: '',
  projectStart: undefined,
  projectTime: 0,
};

for (const prop in currentData) {
  if (currentData[prop]) {
    allFalsey = false;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(allFalsey);
```

But it really would be much easier to use an array, using `for..in` is really silly:

```js
const currentData = {
  title: '',
  description: '',
  projectType: '',
  projectStart: undefined,
  projectTime: 0,
};

const allFalsey = !Object.values(currentData).some(Boolean);
console.log(allFalsey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```js
const CreateProjectData = {
  title: '',
  description: null,
  projectType: 1,
  projectStart: undefined,
  projectTime: 0,
};

for(var key in CreateProjectData){
  if(!CreateProjectData[key])
    console.log(`${key} is false`);
  else
    console.log(`${key} is true`);
}
```